# SASS - Can I define variable within for loop?

Tags: css, sass

```
$x: 100%;
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .item-#{$i} {
    width: $x;
    $x: $x - 10;
  }
}
```

Can I define $x as 100% so it won't be global(if I may say so) and do calculations with it within the loop?
Pass it as an argument maybe? Or it must be a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can entirely base it on the `$i` variable and calculate it on each step (without using recursion). Something like this maybe:

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  $x: 110% - $i * 10;
  .item-#{$i} {
    width: $x;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7328137)

but then (if your real case is not much more complicated than this example) you also don't really need a separate variable and just do:

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .item-#{$i} {
    width: 110% - $i * 10;
  }
}
```

This way you overwrite your `$x` on each step of the iteration. But alternatively you can use Sass' [`if()` function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#if-instance_method) and do something like this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  $x: if($i < 2, 100%, $x - 10);
  .item-#{$i} {
    width: $x;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7333067)

where on the first iteration step you define `$x` and assign its initial value ... then you can modify `$x` in each step of the loop and pass it to the next.

In both cases `$x` is only defined [in the scope](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7333321) of the `@for` directive and you can not access it form the outside (hence it is a *local* variable). But bear in mind that any *global* variable with the same name will get overwritten.